# updating a d3js tree map

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to render a tree map using d3.js that periodically fetches data and animates/transitions based on changes in mostly static data (few values change).  I'm working from the example [here](http://strongriley.github.io/d3/ex/treemap.html).

So I have something along the lines of:

```
var w = 960,
h = 500,
color = d3.scale.category20c();

var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
.size([w, h])
//.sticky(true)
.value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var div = d3.select("#chart").append("div")
.style("position", "relative")
.style("width", w + "px")
.style("height", h + "px");

function update (json) {
  var d = div.data([json]).selectAll("div")
  .data(treemap.nodes, function (d) { return d.name; });

  d.enter().append("div")
  .attr("class", "cell")
  .style("background", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.name) : null; })
  .call(cell)
  .text(function(d) { return d.children ? null : d.name; });

  d.exit().remove();
};

d3.json("flare.json", update);

setTimeout(function () {
  d3.json("flare2.json", update);
}, 3000);

function cell() {
  this
  .style("left", function(d) { return d.x + "px"; })
  .style("top", function(d) { return d.y + "px"; })
  .style("width", function(d) { return d.dx - 1 + "px"; })
  .style("height", function(d) { return d.dy - 1 + "px"; });
}
```

Where flare2.json is a copy of flare.json found [here](http://strongriley.github.io/d3/data/flare.json), but with one node removed.

```
➜  test git:(master) ✗ diff flare.json flare2.json
10d9
<       {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
380c379
< }
\ No newline at end of file
---
> }
```

The problem is, after 3 seconds, the data is fetched and the text for the AgglomerativeCluster is removed, but not the box it was in.  I can't say that I fully understand d3js enough to know what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After RTFM [[1](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808221), [2](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234), [3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218)], I learned that d3.js separates the ideas of updating existing nodes, adding new nodes, and removing dead nodes.  I had the code for adding and removing, but I was missing the update code.  Simply adding this did the trick:

```
d.transition().duration(750).call(cell);
```

After creating `var d` but before the call to `d.enter()`.